# Change Display Value of DataGridViewLinkColumn

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a datagridview with a datagridviewlinkcolumn bound to a text link in my list of objects. The text links are links to files, and the files are buried deep in network storage, making for long links. Is there some way I can change the link display value of the linkcolumn to show only a portion of each full link? ie - just the file name itself?

I've read you can use the same header text for the display value of a link column, but I'm wondering if all of the display values could be different.

So to summarize, is it possible to show part of a file link in the linkcolumn, while all of the parts I want to show will be different, and still have the actual link point to the full file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Not sure if there's a better way to do this, but I added a shortened version of the link to my object, and in my `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` event, I get the object associated with the row `(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)`, and call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` on the fully qualified file path in the object returned.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: @John: did you find any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to achieve this.

First, while creating the `DataGridViewLinkColumn` set `UseColumnTextForLinkValue = false`

Set the `Text` property of the `DataGridViewLinkColumn` to the *full path* of the file which is buried deep in the network storage.

Now, handle `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` and set the `Value` property of the cell to the *display name of the link*

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (excelDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Links"))
        {
             if(e.Value != null)
                e.Value = Path.GetFileName(e.Value.ToString()); //change the display name for Hyperlink
        }
    }
```

To perform any action on clicking of the link you need to handle `CellContentClick` event of `DataGridView` as follows

```
    private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == excelDataGridView.Columns["Links"].Index) //Handling of HyperLink Click
        {
            string cellValue = excelDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            Process.Start(cellValue); //assumes the link points to the text file and opens it in the default text editor
        }
    }
```